# Resolve instance with unity 5.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, unity-container

How do I resolve an instance of a class with the new Unity 5.0.0 Resolve() method?

In Unity 4.0.1 I resolved an instances like the example given below with `SettingsContext`. But this no longer works.
I am thinking it is a matter of giving a second argument to Resolve, but I am not sure howto.

```
var _unity = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
var _settings = _unity.Resolve<SettingsContext>();
```

With UnityConfig class being defined as

```
public class UnityConfig
{
    private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        RegisterTypes(container);
        return container;
    });

    public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
    {
        return container.Value;
    }

    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer unity)
    {
       //all the unity.RegisterType calls
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. As normal, load the container.
2. Next load the named section - the default is "unity", but it could be any tag you want in the config file.
3. Finally, have the section object configure the container.

   ```
   var c = new UnityContainer();    
   var section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
   section.Configure(c);
   var ss = c.Resolve<IStorageSystem>();
   ```

For the **app|web.config**, be sure to reference the updated type definition (see assembly).

```
<configSections>
<section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Unity.Configuration"/>
</configSections>
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
 <container>
   <register type="FileBox.IStorageSystem, FileBox" mapTo="FileBox.StorageSystem.Local.LocalFileSystem, FileBox" >
    <constructor>
      <param name="root">
        <value value =""/>
      </param>
    </constructor>
  </register>
 </container>
```